# Could not load file or assembly microsoft.mshtml in Telerik Reporting

Tags: telerik, visual-studio-2019, telerik-reporting, microsoft.mshtml

I'm using Telrik Reporting and after opened the trdp file in order to modify it , when I select a bloc section to edit it , I got this error :

[image]

**Note:**

I have already added `Microsoft.mshtml` in Visual Studio 2019 and `Copy local` option is set to true but there is no change and I'm still getting this exception .

[image]

How can I solve it?

Comment: That error message says it was trying to load an *assembly* by that name; not that it was trying to find the file `microsoft.mshtml`.  So look for `microsoft.mshtml.dll` perhaps?

Comment: Is it the same , I have loaded it in the references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a heads up, I answered this on the [Telerik Reporting Forums](https://www.telerik.com/forums/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-mshtml-in-telerik-reporting#CPykq9QQU0qCZ9PNKPn3Dw), but I also wanted to share this here with the rest of the community as well. The issue appears to derive from the machine that has Telerik Reporting installed.

Some Telerik Reporting users have reported that Windows Server variants do not include the Microsoft.mshtml in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC). To resolve this, I recommend installing the `Microsoft.mshtml` assembly in the GAC using `gacutil`.

To do this, use the [Developer Command Prompt for VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs) and perform the following steps.

1. Download the [Microsoft.mshtml](https://github.com/ogaudefroy/Unofficial.Microsoft.mshtml/tree/master/lib/net40) assembly and save it to the Downloads folder.
2. Change directory to the Downloads folder in the Developer Command Prompt: `cd %USERPROFILE%\Downloads`
3. Install the assembly in the GAC: `gacutil /i microsoft.mshtml`
4. Verify that it has been installed: `gacutil /l microsoft.mshtml`